# Add relative layout background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am having a relative layout I want to create the layout dynamically the layout in XMl lookes like

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5sp"
        android:background="@drawable/step_background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

I made this like -

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lprams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        lprams.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
```

But how to add the background **I am doing this in a Fragment not in a activity**

Comment: Please clarify your question. can't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try as follows...

```
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lprams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    lprams.setMargins(5,5,5,5);

    layout.setLayoutParams(lprams);

    layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.step_background);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This : -

```
RelativeLayout mRelativeLayoutPopup = new RelativeLayout(context);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
mRelativeLayoutPopup.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);     
mRelativeLayoutPopup.setBackgroundResource(drawable_background);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setBackground`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) for that.

```
Drawable bg_image= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image); 
myLayout.setBackground(bg_image);
```

Hope it helps.